# How to apply rules to a list, before the head of the list?

Tags: list, prolog

I have a set of rules with this form:

```
regla(o,o,o,o).
```

And the way the statement (this is homework) is written, I have a list as input, and I have to apply this rules 2 elements before the list starts (this is possible because it is said that there are infinite symbols before and after the list starts, all being the same).

Now, the problem I have is that I cannot come up with a way to operate to the whole list.

That is, my idea was to make an operation to the head of the list, then recursively to the body of the list, and finally, another operation to the tail of the list.

something like this (it does not work yet, unfortunately):

```
:- ensure_loaded('automaton.pl').

listsplit([H1,H2,H3|T], H1,H2,H3, T).


%regla(o,o,H1,Output).**This would be the operation to the head of the list**


%append(Output,Accumulator).%we manually add the first and last elements of the list
%cells(InList,OutList). Caso Base:
%cells( [ ], _).%perhaps cells( [ ], []). would be less dangerous


cells(Input, Result):-cellsAUX(Input, Accumulator, Result).%base case removed because examples use it in the equivalent to  the cellsAUX call

cellsAUX([], Result, Result).
cellsAUX(Input, Accumulator, Result):-**This would be the operations to the body of the list, calling itself recursively, and adding the results of each iteration to an Accumulator**
            listsplit(Input,Head1Arg1,Head2Arg1,Head3Arg1,T),
            regla(Head1Arg1,Head2Arg1,Head3Arg1,Output),
            cellsAUX([Head2Arg1,Head3Arg1|T] , [Output|Accumulator], Result).
```

Is there some approach to make this without so many sub cases? I just can't shake this feeling I am making it more difficult than it is needed.

For reference, the input would be something like oxoxo, and as I said, it is assumed everything before and after are o's.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the poorly formed question, I do not have enough vocabulary to "call" this problem the right way.